# Ubuntu 14.04 display issue from VMWare console

Tags: display, vmware

I wonder if some can help with my problem. I am moving over my business infrastructure from Microsoft products to Ubuntu 14.04, although I am also trialling CentOS and straight Debian too. I currently have everything running on a pair of VMWare 4.1 hosts running on two Dell PE2950III servers (2xquad Intel Zeons and 64GB RAM each). Both hosts are current as far as updates are concerned.

Everything is going OK apart from an issue with the Ubuntu desktop when accessed via vCenter console - if I set the display to anything higher than 800x600 the screen and launcher is duplicated every 800 pixels to the right. This also covers anything that should be there.

I understand that Ubuntu 14.04 uses 3D acceleration which I'm sure the standard VMWare display driver doesn't support. I have tried every video RAM setting in vSphere and every possible screen resolution within ubuntu over 800x600 and still get the same affect.

I have installed the open_vm_tools package with no luck. I have seen a few suggestions of moving down to an earlier version but I would like to get 14.04 working if possible. As a beginner I like the ease of use that Ubuntu gives me while I'm learning.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cracked it :) By accident I installed kernel 3.14.0-031400 rebooted and vCenter console now shows my desktops correctly. I downloaded this version quite by accident but glad I did as the latest version (3.16.1Utopic) doesn't fix the issue. I'm going to leave it at this for the time being as I have lots of learning and work to do before I can fully move all of my infrastructure over to Linux.

Hope the above helps others in the same position as me.